# Error "type text/html, is not text/css" when redirecting the user to a web page through .htaccess

Tags: html, css, apache, .htaccess

I have a website running on an apache server.
I have created a new page (mantenimiento.php) to automatically redirect users there while I deploy to the production environment.

I have added the following code to the .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/mantenimiento.php$
#RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^x.xxx.xxx.xxx //my public ip
#RewriteRule $ /mantenimiento.php [R=302,L]
```

(I am new to using rewrite rules)

I have specified my ip so that I can work with the page.
The rest of the users should see the page mantenimiento.php

However, when accessing the website with an anonymous browser like Tor, I see the error:

```
The stylesheet <my-site-web> was not loaded because its MIME type, "text/html", is not "text/css".
```

[image]

Styles and images are not uploaded.

I think the appended part in .htaccess causes this to fail.
If I comment the lines of the .htaccess the styles are loaded correctly.

How can I make the styles and images load?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to exclude `js/css/images` from the new rule:

```sh
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/mantenimiento\.php$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^x.xxx.xxx.xxx
RewriteRule !\.(css|js|png|jpe?g|gif|ico)$ /mantenimiento.php [R=302,L,NC]
```

Otherwise web browser will try to render output from `/mantenimiento.php` as css or image resource.